# Tracing family tree if grandparents moved to UK from Pakistan?

Tags: family-tree

I have lived in the uk all my life and I want to trace my family tree back as far as possible.

However, my father came to the uk from a place called Swat valley in north west Pakistan and his family are still there and my mothers parents came to the uk when they were young from the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a more specific question about your genealogy and family history, I recommend starting your research at the free FamilySearch.org site.

There you will find a [Pakistan Genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Pakistan_Genealogy) page which says that it is a:

> Guide to Pakistan ancestry, family history and genealogy parish
>   registers, transcripts, census records, birth records, marriage
>   records, and death records.

I suspect that your parents and grandparents may have been born less than 100 years ago so if you have trouble finding answers to specific questions about your Pakistani ancestors feel free to ask them here as new questions but pay close attention to our [Privacy Policy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).